# Flash Player AS -> webcam get buffer bytes

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, get, byte, webcam

I am working on a flash video chat system. I need to get the video buffer bytes from the webcam to be able to transfer the video content over a socket server. I am not sure how to do this, does anyone have any ideas? Thanks.

I know how to use the webcam basics, the code:

```
var camera = Camera.getCamera();
var video = new Video(camera.width, camera.height);
video.attachCamrea(camera);

/*
 I need something like
 var byte_buffer = video.getBytes();
*/
```

I don't know how to do this, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem. You'll need to create a `BitmapData` object and 'draw' your display object - the one referenced by `video` variable - 'into' this bitmap data. You can then access the pixels through, say, the `getPixels` method which returns a `ByteArray` which is your *de facto* buffer class in Flash Player. The drawing is like taking a snapshot bitmap copy of your display object.

Find out more at Adobe ActionScript 3 Reference which should be your best friend as long as you program the Flash Player: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html

Here is some code for illustration:

```
var bd = new BitmapData(320, 240, false, 0x000000);
bd.draw(video);
var byte_buffer = bd.getPixels(); /// For example...
```

Comment: Well, he might loop taking snapshots every say, 100 ms and send the buffer obtained with `getPixels` down the wire. Or are you asking me a trick question?